# Having trouble with Relationships in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, foreign-key-relationship

In the picture below, I'm wanting the relationship(s) between 'Employee', 'Emp_Proj' and 'Project' to be like those between 'Employee', 'Emp_Skill' and 'Skill'.

As it is currently, from the 'Employee' table I can view (by clicking the little '+' that appears in the 'Employee' record) any instances of 'Emp_Skill' associated with that 'Employee' and the description of the corresponding 'Skill'.

But, when trying to do the same thing with 'Employee', 'Emp_Proj' and 'Project', when I click on the '+' in the 'Employee' record, a dialogue box appears asking me to choose which 'subdatasheet' to insert.

Choosing any of the possible options means I can only ever view that one.

Is this a common, easily fixed, issue born of my inexperience with databases, or can it not be done?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
AUS_Doug.

[image: The relationships of the database in question. I'm wanting to link 'Employee' and 'Emp_Proj' in the same way that I have linked it to 'Emp_Skill']

Comment: This is sort of off topic, but why are you using the mapping tables in the first place? Since you have a 1-to-1 mapping betweek SKILL and EMP_SKILL, why not just map a 1-to-many relationship between EMPLOYEE and SKILL directly? And then, same thing with the projects?

Comment: That was my thinking originally - and I may well end up doing that - but in the our assignment specifications we were given an ERD showing the relationship between 'Employee' and 'Skill' as many-to-many. We were told to try and get rid of many-to-many relationships if we can, and this is the easiest way I could think of doing that.

Comment: Ok. Not too sure about the actual problem you are having in Access, but your current setup isn't a true many-to-many relationship. You should change the relationship between SKILL and EMP_SKILL to be 1-to-many, instead of 1-to-1

Comment: ... and replicate that or Projects a well. You may find, modifying the structure may remove your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it didn't help. After I have linked 'Employee_ID' from 'Employee' into both 'Emp_Skill' and 'Emp_Proj', I still get asked to choose a 'subdatasheet' when expanding the record (by clicking the small '+' that appears next to a record for 'Employee' in the Datasheet view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show related data in table view was designed as a helper method to explore relationships. But is designed to show only one 'child' relation each time.

In my databases, I tend to disable the master/detail navegation, preciselly because Access ask the user what relation show. Instead of automatic relations in table views, I recomend you to use master/detail forms.

Comment: Ah there we go; Owing to my 'new-ness' to Access, I hadn't even looked at Forms yet. Just set some up then and now everything is peachy, thanks a bunch fir that.